# How to add the "--deploy-mode cluster" option to my scala code

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-standalone

209/5000
Hello
I want to add the option "--deploy-mode cluster" to my code scala:

```
  val sparkConf = new SparkConfig ().setMaster ("spark: //192.168.60.80:7077")
```

Without using the shell (the command. \ Spark-submit)

i whant to  usage  the " spark.submit.deployMode " in scala

Answer (score 11):

with SparkConfig:

```
//set up the spark configuration and create contexts
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkApp").setMaster("spark: //192.168.60.80:7077")

val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf).set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
```

with SparkSession:

```
val spark = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .appName("SparkApp")
   .master("spark: //192.168.60.80:7077")
   .config("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster")
   .enableHiveSupport()
   .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf ().setMaster ("spark: //192.168.60.80:7077").set("spark.submit.deployMode","cluster")
```

Comment: val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .set("spark.submit.deployMode" ,"cluster") 
    .setMaster("spark://master:7077")
    .setAppName("wordcount")

Comment: My address is: 192.168.60.90, is not the same in the master host: 192.168.60.80

No import, no configuration between driver and master

Note that I use Eclipse maven project

Comment: which version of spark you are using?

Comment: i'm using  the spark 2.1.0